# update file path is notworking

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

I have a product list,there I can Add, Update, Delete Products. Add, Delete is working fine. When I update a product, everything is updating well, except image's path. its simply remove the old file path and update empty value. Even when i try to edit a product, other values fetch from DB correctly, except file path, it simply shows "No file chosen". actually it should show the file path no?. so, only it gives empty value when i try to Post this form value. Please anyone help me to solve this problem.
Here, what I've done so far.
Thanks in Advance.

Products.php

```
<?php include_once("auth.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<table border="solid 1px black;">
<tr><td colspan="6" align="right"><a href="product_form.php">Add new</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<th>S. No</th>
<th>Product Code</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Available Qunatity</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Operations</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete_id'])) {
 $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id =".$_REQUEST['delete_id']);
 header("Location:products.php");
} else if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['product_code'])){
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["type"] == "image/png"))) {
  if ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["product_img_name"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_img_name"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/" . $_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"]);
      $path = "images/". $_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"];
      }}}
$id = $_POST['id'];
$product_code = $_POST['product_code'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$image = mysql_query(" SELECT product_img_name FROM products WHERE id='$id'");
$image_fetch= mysql_fetch_array($image);
$oldimage= $image_fetch['product_img_name'];
#################### Is this correct ? Why its not working??? ########
if(isset($_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"]) AND ($_FILES["product_img_name"]["name"]) ==''){
$product_img_name = $oldimage;
}
else{
$product_img_name = $path;
}

#########################
$price = $_POST['price'];
$available_qty = $_POST['available_qty'];
$date = date( 'd-m-y h:i:s');
if($id == '') {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (`id`,`product_code`, `product_name`,`product_desc`, `product_img_name`, `price`,`available_qty`, `date`) VALUES ('$id','$product_code', '$product_name','$product_desc', '$product_img_name', '$price','$available_qty', '$date')");
} else { $query = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET `product_code`='$product_code', `product_name` = '$product_name', `product_desc` ='$product_desc', `product_img_name` = '$product_img_name', `price` = '$price', `available_qty` = '$available_qty', `date` = '$date' WHERE id = $id");  }

if($query) { header("Location:products.php"); } else { header("Location:product_form.php"); }

}
 else {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['product_code']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['product_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['product_desc']; ?></td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $result['product_img_name']; ?>" height="100px" width="100px"></td>
<td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['available_qty']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['date']; ?></td>
<td><a href="product_form.php?eidt_id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Edit</a> | <a href="products.php?delete_id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
} }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

product_form.php

```
    <?php include_once("auth.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['eidt_id'])) {    
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =".$_REQUEST['eidt_id']);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  
    $id = $result['id'];
    $product_code = $result['product_code'];
    $product_name = $result['product_name'];
    $product_desc = $result['product_desc'];
    $product_img_name = $result['product_img_name'];
    $price = $result['price'];
    $available_qty = $result['available_qty'];
    $date = $result['date'];  
} else {
    $id = '';
    $product_code = '';
    $product_name = '';
    $product_desc = '';
    $product_img_name = '';
    $price = '';
    $available_qty = '';
    $date = '';
}
?>
<form action="products.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Product Code</label>
<input type="text" name="product_code" value="<?=$product_code?>" ><br/>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?=$product_name?>" ><br/>
<label>Description</label>
<input type="text" name="product_desc" value="<?=$product_desc?>"><br/>
<label>Upload Image</label>
<img src="<?=$product_img_name?>">
<input type="file" name="product_img_name" value="<?=$product_img_name?>"><br/>
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?=$price?>"><br/>
<label>Available Quantity</label>
<input type="text" name="available_qty" value="<?=$available_qty?>"><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think your code is not getting the esle case which $path set, so please review it and be sure that your code is getting to that else. thats why your database row's image path updating with null.This means your old image name is not same with current name but your $path is not setting. This is the problem.

Comment: Most probably your uploaded image type is something different from your allowed list. NOT: if i were you i dont validate mime type with provided data from $_FILES some bad guys can manipulate it easly you should check the mime type in your server with file functions in php

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks for helping me to Identifying the problem. now it works fine.Since I'm new to PHP, can you give me a link to useful PHP file functions please?. That will be very Helpful. Once again Thanks @Santa'shelper

Comment: i like to use [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)